# Как загрузить в базу данных postgresql файл sql?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть файл sql, но как его правильно выполнить не знаю
Файл начинается так, дальше следуют прочие команды создания таблиц и их заполнение
[image: Начало файла sql]

Comment: В [документации](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/app-pgdump#PG-DUMP-EXAMPLES) есть примеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать pgsql

```
pgsql - f filepath
```